# Google Drive; changing file permissions error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So. I'm wracking my brain because I have no idea what the issue could be. All I want is to copy an existing Template file, and share it to anyone in the Domain with the Link.

```
function copyFile() {
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "MM-dd-yyyy");
  var file = DocsList.find("testDocument")[0];
  var copy = file.makeCopy("testDocument" + formattedDate);
  copy.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
}
```

Yet it keeps throwing;

> TypeError: Cannot find function setSharing in object File.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use autocomplete in the script editor to avoid such issues, it will automatically suggest available methods.:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Drive Service` instead of `Docs List` to set the sharing.  There is no `setSharing` method for the File type in DocsList.  It's kind of confusing because there is both a `File` type in `Drive Service` and `Docs List`, but `setSharing` isn't available to the File type in `DocsList`.

`Drive Service` does have a `makeCopy` method though:

[makeCopy Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy())

So I would use `Drive Service` instead of `Docs List`.